# Selenium in Actual Android Device like 'Samsung Galaxy Tab'

Tags: android, selenium, device

I want to ask if we can set up the selenium testing framework on an Android Device like a 'Samsung Galaxy Tab' and perform testing of 'video playing' on the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems possible:
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver